# A Gamma function equality

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

This was an equality written in p15, Titchmarsh,

> $$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ \sin y }{y^{s+1}} \,dy = - \Gamma(-s) \sin \frac{1}{2} s \pi $$

How is this true? The RHS, by definition is equal to 
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-y} \sin \frac{1}{2} s\pi }{y^{s+1}} \,dy $$ which I do not see how it equates to the LHS.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but we do have:
$$I=\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{x^{s+1}}~\mathrm dx$$

Comment: maybe using the identity $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: You need to read a complex analysis book. For every $\Re(a) > 0$ and $\Re(s) > 1$ : $\int_0^\infty (ax)^{s-1}e^{-ax} d(ax) = \Gamma(s)$ follows by the Cauchy integral theorem, or analytic continuation, or the identity theorem, or by continuity at $\infty$ of the analytic function such that $F'(z)  = e^{-z}z^{s-1}$, where $a^{s-1} = e^{(s-1) \log a}$. By continuity it stays true for $\Re(s) \in (0,1)$ and $\Re(a) = 0$, and the formula follows.